# My text file has values as 01012017 01022017 01032017

Tags: batch-file

My text file has values as

```
01012017
01022017
01032017
```

Here is my batch file code

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (text file) do (
set "result=%%a"
set "YYYY=%result:~4,4%"
set "MM=%result:~0,2%"
set "DD=%result:~2,2%"
set "date-yesterday=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%"
set "filename-yesterday=%MM%_%DD%_%YYYY%"
"%filename-yesterday%"
"%date-yesterday%"
)
```

getting output as

```
01/03/2017
01_03_2017
01/03/2017
01_03_2017
01/03/2017
01_03_2017
```

But need output as

```
01/01/2017
01_01_2017
01/02/2017
01_02_2017
01/03/2017
01_03_2017
```

Note: Here set "result=%%a" up to this line for loop works. after that it takes last line value of the text ie. 01032017

Anyone please help on this

Comment: Search for `delayed expansion` using the `search` facility in the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you with the solution from Magoo's comment.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("text file.ext") Do (Set "result=%%A"
    Set "filename-yesterday=!result:~0,2!/!result:~2,2!/!result:~4,4!"
    Set "date-yesterday=!filename-yesterday:/=_!
    Echo=!filename-yesterday!
    Echo=!date-yesterday!)
```

Don't create a variable if your not going to use it later though:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("text file.ext") Do (Set "result=%%A"
    Echo=!result:~0,2!/!result:~2,2!/!result:~4,4!
    Echo=!result:~0,2!_!result:~2,2!_!result:~4,4!)
```